Pop index out of range
tengo un problema en este programa no va bien el trozo de código que se encarga de darle una posición a cada piloto
    import random
class piloto():
    def __init__(self, nombre, posicion):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.posicion = posicion
    def adelantar(self):
        self.posicion += 1
    def perder_puesto(self):
        if self.posicion != 20:
            self.posicion -= 1
    def dar_nombre(self):
        return self.nombre
class carrera():
    def __init__(self):
        
        
        self.parrilla = array_pilotos
    def ajustar_parrilla(self, array):    
        self.parrilla.append(array)
        
    def resultados(self):
       random.shuffle(self.parrilla)
       posibilidades = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
       for p in self.parrilla:
        posicion = posibilidades.pop(0)
        
        posibilidades.pop(posicion)
        print(f"{p} ha salido en la posicion {posicion}")


array_pilotos = ["Max Verstappen", "Sergio Perez", "Charles Leclerc", "Carlos Sainz", "Lando Norris", "Oscar Piastri", "Lance Stroll", "Fernando Alonso", "George Russell", "Lewis Hamilton", "Pierre Gasly", "Esteban Ocon ", "Valteri Bottas", "Guanyu Zhou", "Kevin Magnussen", "Nico Hulkenberg", "Yuki tsunoda", "Daniel Ricciardo", "Logan Sargeant", "Alexander albon"]

c = carrera()
c.resultados()

ayuda por favor, el programa no va y no tengo ni la más remota idea, me da un error que es pop index out of range en la octava vez que se ejecuta el range del resultados

no soy experto en python... pero si hiciste pop(0) y anduvo, entonces el array (o como sea que se llame en python) esta indexado en 0, entonces el 20 no existe, existe del 0 al 19 ;)

Sugerencia: Puedes reemplazar [1, 2, ..., 20] con [i + 1 for i in range(20)]

@Rodrigo aún mejor: list(range(1,21))

Es simplemente que la linea:
posibilidades.pop(posicion)

no sirve de nada... aparte de causar el error.
posicion = posibilidades.pop(0)

extrae el primer item (indice 0) de la lista posibilidades (eliminandolo de la misma). A posicion se le asigna una referencia a ese item, que es el 1 en la primera iteracion, el 2 en la segunda, etc. Ese valor lo usas de indice para aplicar de nuevo pop() sobre la misma lista, quedando:
# Primera iteración: pop(0) + pop(1)
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

# Segunda iteración: pop(0) + pop(2)
[4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

# Tercera iteración: pop(0) + pop(4)
[5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

# Cuarta iteración: pop(0) + pop(5)
[7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

# Cuarta iteración: pop(0) + pop(7)
[8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]

# Quinta iteración: pop(0) + pop(8)
[9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19]

En la sexta iteracion seria pop(0) + pop(9), aquí tenemos el problema, la lista tiene 8 items (luego el indice mayor es 7) por lo que pop(9) genera el error mencionado ya que no existe el indice 9.
Elimina esa linea:
def resultados(self):
    random.shuffle(self.parrilla)
    posibilidades = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
    for p in self.parrilla:
        posicion = posibilidades.pop(0)
        print(f"{p} ha salido en la posicion {posicion}")

No obstante, con tu código actual, usar pop() sobre esa lista no tiene muchos sentido y es muy ineficiente. Puedes iterar de forma paralela sobre ambas listas/iterables usando zip():
def resultados(self):
    random.shuffle(self.parrilla)
    posiciones = range(1, len(self.parrilla) + 1)
    for posicion, piloto in zip(posiciones, self.parrilla):
        print(f"{piloto} ha salido en la posicion {posicion}")

O mejor aún, simplemente usar enumerate():
def resultados(self):
    random.shuffle(self.parrilla)
    for posicion, piloto in enumerate(self.parrilla, start=1):
        print(f"{piloto} ha salido en la posicion {posicion}")


Supongo que la idea cuando termines de implementarlo será usar la clase Piloto para que self.parrilla sea una lista de objetos de dicha clase. Si te es más apropiado, puedes también generar la lista con las posiciones y usarla para aleatorizar en vez de hacerlo sobre self.parrilla directamente, asignando cada posición al atributo de la clase Piloto, algo como:
def resultados(self):
    posiciones = random.sample(
        range(1, len(self.parrilla) + 1),
        k=len(self.parrilla)
    )
    for posicion, piloto in zip(posiciones, self.parrilla):
        piloto.posicion = posicion


muchísimas gracias eres un gigachad .
